# Passing A Parameter for a VBA Recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, parameter-passing, recordset

I have a query that has a parameter that is not part of the results columns as below.
It usually pops up when I execute the query.

```
PARAMETERS SelectedDate DateTime;
Select col1,col2, col3 from qry
where col4 = [SelectedDate]
```

I need to create a VBA recordset for only col1 & col2.
Can anyone please advise how I can pass this parameter? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand it you want to pass a parameter from VBA to Access Query?

If that is so, you need to create a module in VBA.

It could be like this:

```
Public Str As String

Public Function str_move() As String
str_move = Str
End Function
```

So Str is your variable in VBA.
In your query you can now write `str_move()` and hence get this Str value.

NOTICE: The module name can not be the same as the function name. Name the module m_MoveVariables

It does not matter - The module name is not used in the queries.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: The module name does matter, and the code you gave will not work, at least not without modification.

Comment: Why will it not work? It works here. I copied it from my own module... Which i use every day.

Comment: My comment was focused on The module name same as Function name.

Comment: I dont understand. I wrote that the names could not be the same. But that the name didnt matter (as long as they were not equal). Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

You can use your `SELECT` statement as the data source for a `DAO.Recordset`, and then supply the parameter value before you open it.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSelect As String

strSelect = "PARAMETERS SelectedDate DateTime;" & vbCrLf & _
    "Select col1,col2, col3 from qry" & vbCrLf & _
    "where col4 = [SelectedDate];"
Debug.Print strSelect '<-- inspect this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g to go there

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
qdf.Parameters("SelectedDate").Value = Date '<-- whatever Date/Time value you want here
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

Answer (score 0):

You could even simply use a Recordset, without using QueryDef object,

```
Dim rsObj As DAO.Recordset

Set rsObj = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT col1, col2 FROM qry WHERE col4 = " & _
                                    Format(Date(), "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"))

'Date() can be replace with any Date or Date Variable.
```